# Want to store small wav files in mongo database and load them async from client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am building a site and for it's backend which runs node with express I would like to add a method that will async retrieve small audio files to play.
I am using mongoose which now only serves straightforward collections.
I have 2 questions:
How will I add those files?
What encoding should I use?